# Zero joins with null in the null-safe join

Tags: apache-spark, join, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, null-safety

I have noticed that `0` joins with `null` when using null-safe join ([`eqNullSafe`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.Column.eqNullSafe.html)).

```py
df1 = spark.createDataFrame([(1, ), (None, )], ['df1_id'])
df2 = spark.createDataFrame([(None, ), (0, )], ['df2_id'])

df1.join(df2, df1.df1_id.eqNullSafe(df2.df2_id), 'right').show()
#+------+------+
#|df1_id|df2_id|
#+------+------+
#|  null|     0|
#|  null|  null|
#+------+------+

df2.join(df1, df1.df1_id.eqNullSafe(df2.df2_id), 'left').show()
#+------+------+
#|df2_id|df1_id|
#+------+------+
#|     0|  null|
#|  null|  null|
#+------+------+
```

How do I make `null` join only with `null`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do inner join here

```py
df1.join(df2, df1.df1_id.eqNullSafe(df2.df2_id), 'inner').show()
```

Right now for 0 in right and there is no match in the left df, and we are doing right join that's why pyspark is keeping 0 in right df and it is becoming null in `df1_id`.